# Is this javascript snippet considered bad?

Tags: javascript

I like making my code as succinct as possible but maybe this is unreadable?

```
var filters = {};
function addFilter(type, name) {
  filters[type] && filters[type].push(name) || ( filters[type] = [name] );
}
```

or even (as pointed out in answers):

```
var filters = {};
function addFilter(type, name) {
  filters[type] ? filters[type].push(name) : ( filters[type] = [name] );
}
```

-edit--

Not unreadable but maybe bad style? The alternative would have been to write out

```
var filters = {};
function addFilter(type, name) {
  if (!filters[type]) {
    filters[type]= [];
  }
  filters[type].push(name);
}
```

Comment: Unreadable to whom? You? You in six months? You in a year after working in Objective-C? Somebody else who worked on the project with you? Somebody else who knows Javascript?

Comment: Well it's an opionion then, I know Javascript and consider this unreadable but many other good Javascript programmers consider it very readable, for instance the authors of bootstrap [famously](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3057) :P

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean unreadable but bad form? I edited the question. Maybe to another javascript developer? I just want to know what people think about writing it out the first way as opposed to the longer method?

Comment: I am for dev. version using readable code. And for prodation using minifer version

Comment: Make everything explicit, and use a minifier when releasing. You can't go wrong with that.

Comment: Yes, I'd say abusing short-circuit operators is bad practice. Also consider early returns.

Comment: As well as readability, consider how easy this code will be to alter if  you need to later (you may well end up reverting to the longer version if it gets any more complicated) and perhaps also, how much time you wasted condensing it to a single line.

Comment: Related, would be a duplicate if it were on SO: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5976/is-it-bad-practice-to-rely-on-short-circuit-evaluation-instead-of-using-the-if-c/5982#5982

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Languages have idioms and patterns for good reasons. In particular, Javascript has the `if`/`else` statement that is designed precisely for this purpose. Code should be written so that it is easy to *read*, because in the future it will be read far more often than it is written.

I would not accept the above "succinct" code in a code review.

Answer (score 2):

You could at least use a ternary:

```
filters[type] ? filters[type].push(name) : ( filters[type] = [name] );
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the expanded version of your code, but a little more succinctly:

```
if ( ! filters[type] ) filters[type] = [];

filters[type].push(name);
```

This results in two statement being run when the array is first created, but I find this way more readable.

Comment: @downvoter - Downvotes are for bad answers, not for when you disagree :)

Comment: Not the downvoter, but arguably a bad answer (in your opinion) is one you disagree with. :)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - Downvotes are for *factually* wrong answers. Coming to think of it, this is an opinionated question, and is probably off topic...

Comment: Also not the downvoter - I answered the same thing (although I missed first-post) - my thinking is, javascript guys use ternaries all the time. Google's Javascript style-guide permits them (with some caveats towards line length..). I suspect && and || would be more confusing to 'web guys' than seeing a ternary anyway. I hate them myself, but.. when in rome...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with ternaries.  There are two particularly evil uses of them, though:  chaining them (like `cond1 ? a : cond2 ? b : c`), and *using them to trigger actions* like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say unnecessarily unreadable. It also depends on what you are working on and who you are working for. If you are sure that you are the only person going to be supporting this application, then maybe this would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is readable but also misleading. What i expect from function called addFilter is to add some filter or if such a exists i should get exception or false or -1 (something that tells me its duplicated)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `;` after `var filters = {}` and also, the second form is way better because it's easier for a new coder to understand it stright away (or yourself in the future).
You could use your first form and comment it, but as Sammy Larbi said in [Common Excuses Used To Comment Code](http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2008/6/18/Common-Excuses-Used-To-Comment-Code-and-What-To-Do-About-Them/2293), if your feel your code is too complex to understand without comments, your code is probably *just bad*.

Answer (score 0):

Using && and || might be a little confusing to Javascript guys who're more familiar with ternaries.

```
function addFilter(type,name) {
    filters[type] ? filters[type].push(name) : filters[type] = [name];
}
```